# Why is my JFileChooser not storing it's results for the rest of the code?

Tags: java, swing

In Java, I'm trying to set a JFileChooser to select files, then store the file names for use in a stringbuilder. So, say I have code like this

```
    try
    {
        //Basic game launching command.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe");
        }
        for(File f : CustomContent.getSelectedFiles()){
            sb.append(" -file ").append(f.getName());

        }
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
    }
```

And in another section I have this, for a jButton called "CustomContent"

```
  private void CustomContentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    final JFileChooser CustomContent = new JFileChooser();
    CustomContent.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    int returnVal = CustomContent.showOpenDialog(CustomContent);
    String file = CustomContent.getSelectedFile().toString();
```

Why isn't it working? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is a minimal example program. I think I've included everything. It's from netbeans, so I'm not 100% sure. 
If I left anything out, let me know.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

/**
 *
 * @author Loismustdie555
 */
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJPanel
     */
    public NewJPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        CustomContentButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        RunGameButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        CustomContentButton.setText("Files");
        CustomContentButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CustomContentButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        RunGameButton.setText("Run");
        RunGameButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                RunGameButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(CustomContentButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(RunGameButton)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(CustomContentButton)
                    .addComponent(RunGameButton))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void RunGameButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        try
        {
            //Basic game launching command.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe");
            for(File f : CustomContentButton.getSelectedFiles()){
                sb.append(" -file ").append(f.getName());

            }

            //Launch the game
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            //Log Error
        }
    }                                             

    private void CustomContentButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        final JFileChooser CustomContentResults = new JFileChooser();
        CustomContentResults.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        int returnVal = CustomContentResults.showOpenDialog(CustomContentResults);
        String file = CustomContentResults.getSelectedFile().toString();
    }                                                   


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton CustomContentButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton RunGameButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: There us nothing wrong with your method. It works fine. may be there is something missing from ur code. what is the error?

Comment: I'm using netbeans, and it's saying Cannot find symbol .getSelectedFiles()

Comment: You're asking "why is my code not working", but it doesn't look like you've shown enough information for others to answer. For better help, please post a small compilable (or near to compilable as possible) program that **demonstrates for us your problem**. Otherwise you're forcing us to guess, and most of us are not very good at this.

Comment: I'm still totally lost here. Maybe someone else can see the problem, but if not, you really want to consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in other words isolate the problem and post the minimal program that demonstrates it. Also post the **complete** error message leaving nothing out.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that I can see in the code that you've posted so far (other than that you're not following Java naming convention) is that you're declaring your CustomContent variable (which should be named "customContent") locally, suggesting that whatever CustomContent object you're using where you declare it, is not the same one where you are trying to extract data from it.

---

**Edit**
Regarding your new code, you're calling getSelectedFiles() on CustomContentButton, a JButton(??). This of course won't work.

---

**Edit 2**
Your whole program set up looks off. You should get your files from the JFileChooser immediately after the user uses the JFileChooser, so perhaps in the ActionListener where you make the JFileChooser visible -- get the information at the bottom of that listener, store the information in a field, and then you can use it in your class.

And please learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter.

Following these suggestions as well as following good code formatting practices will allow others (such as us!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, will allow your future self to better understand just what you were thinking 6 months ago when you wrote the code.

---

**Edit 3**
For example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NewJPanel2 extends JPanel {
   private File[] selectedFiles = null;

   // Actions that are used by my buttons
   private RunAction runAction = new RunAction("Run");
   private FileAction fileAction = new FileAction("Files");

   public NewJPanel2() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

      // create my buttons using the actions
      add(new JButton(fileAction));
      add(new JButton(runAction));
   }

   // my run action
   private class RunAction extends AbstractAction {
      public RunAction(String name) {
         super(name);  // give button its name text
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);  
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // alt-key mnemonic
         setEnabled(false); // disable this action at start
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // TODO use selectedFiles to launch new program

         // just to show that the files are accessable
         for (File file : selectedFiles) {
            System.out.println(file);
         }
      }
   }

   private class FileAction extends AbstractAction {

      public FileAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         final JFileChooser customContentResults = new JFileChooser();
         customContentResults.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
         int returnVal = customContentResults.showOpenDialog(customContentResults);
         if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            selectedFiles = customContentResults.getSelectedFiles();
            if (selectedFiles != null && selectedFiles.length > 0) {

               // only enable runAction if Files have been selected
               runAction.setEnabled(true);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      NewJPanel2 mainPanel = new NewJPanel2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("NewJPanel2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I posted what you requested (I think). Not 100% sure what I'm doing tbh. So I apologize if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Loismustdie555: you're calling `getSelectedFiles()` on CustomContentButton, a JButton(??).

Comment: Woops. It appears I am. But if I rename CustomContentButton.getSelectedFiles()) to CustomContentResults.getSelectedFiles()) it spits out another error

Comment: @Loismustdie555: Your whole program set up looks off. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: @Loismustdie555: OK, but I'm not sure how that is relevant to your current problem. Again, I suggest that you store your File[] into a field, perhaps called `selectedFiles`, and then use that array in your run method.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but could you make an example code for me?

Comment: @Loismustdie555: for example.